# Mule Subflow and Flowreference

Tags: mule

I am using mule 3.2.1 and having four main flows and one subflow. In each main flow I am calling subflow using flow reference. In subflow, how many instance will be created as I am calling four time the subflow? Any performance issue will occur or any wrong on this approach? Please suggest me on this approach.

**Four main flows.**

```
<flow name="DetailsFlow1" doc:name="DetailsFlow1">
    <inbound-endpoint address="${fd.address}" exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="Generic Point"/>
    <logger message="PAYLOAD #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <cxf:jaxws-service port="80" serviceClass="com.integration.IFixedDepositDetails" mtomEnabled="true" enableMuleSoapHeaders="false" doc:name="SOAP"/>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="oprationService == 'fd-con'" evaluator="ognl">
            <processor-chain>
                <component class="com.integration.impl.FixedDepositDetailsImpl" doc:name="Java"/>
                <flow-ref name="fdcasterflows1Flow1" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>                    
            </processor-chain>
        </when>
    </choice>        
</flow>


<flow name="DetailsFlow2" doc:name="DetailsFlow2">
<flow-ref name="fdcasterflows1Flow1" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>              
</flow>


<flow name="DetailsFlow3" doc:name="DetailsFlow3">
<flow-ref name="fdcasterflows1Flow1" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>              
</flow>


<flow name="DetailsFlow4" doc:name="DetailsFlow4">
<flow-ref name="fdcasterflows1Flow1" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>              
</flow>
```

**One subflow**

```
 <sub-flow name="fdcasterflows1Flow1" doc:name="fdcasterflows1Flow1">
    <component class="com.GetDetails" doc:name="Java"/>
</sub-flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the question you have mentioned above, the component is created in Prototype scope. So there will be an instance created for each request of the component.

So in the above case it is four instances as the subflow is called four times.

If there are going to be too many requests for the subflow which is using the Component then there will definitely be a performance hit. So in such a case you can shoose the polled components.

More on this at the Mule site.
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Object+Scopes

Hope this helps.....  :)

Answer (score 0):

As @user1760178 said, four instances of your component will be created and better to use pooled-component configuration. But If your Java component is stateless component, it is even better to associate `singleton` scope to your component than pooled-component.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the question you have mentioned above, the component is created in Prototype scope. So there will be an instance created for each request of the component.

So in the above case it is four instances as the subflow is called four times.

If there are going to be too many requests for the subflow which is using the Component then there will definitely be a performance hit. So in such a case you can shoose the polled components.